# Whats the housing space of a golemite?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was attacking in clan war, in which a Golem exploded into two golemites as usual. But one of the golemites triggered the spring trap and it bounced off. So definitely the space of it is less than or equal to 15 (correct me if it isn't 15).

So the question arises, what would be the housing of golemite after explosion of a Golem?

Skeletons spawned by witches also get bounced off by spring traps, so how many housing spaces do skeletons take?

Comment: And additionally skeletons fit into this question as well

Comment: @ModDL Yes you may edit the question as required to increase information received in answer

Comment: Read this, you will get some idea as no one is sure about this. http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Golem/Golemite  (read comment of crimmson )

Comment: I'm not sure about the usefulness of this question?

Comment: well knowing these values may help to determine if a skeleton and golemite trigger spring trap, what would be the outcome?

Comment: You already know however that they are vulnerable to spring traps, so theoretically 15 or below

Comment: I meant will   1)  skeleton go off    OR   2) golemite go off    OR    3)both of them will go off

Comment: note that they are stepping on one tile together and spring trap is in that tile

Answer (score 3):

According to the Clash of Clans Wiki, [Golemites take 6 housing space](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Golem/Golemite) and [Skeletons take 1 housing space](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Witch/Skeleton).

Comment: I think that the only way to determine it is by testing.

Comment: It seems like this answer misses the point of the question

Comment: The question of knowing the exact space is interresting to know if an upgraded spring trap will bounce 2 golemites (or how many other types of units it can bounce together with one golemite)... If the housing is 9, a level 4+ trap will bounce 2 of them.